# Call constructor with parameter inside Java stream with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to call a constructor for MySortedSet that takes in a Comparator c as a parameter. How can I modify this to do so?

```
public MySortedSet<E> subSet(E fromElement, E toElement) {
     return list.stream()
            .filter(x -> (list.indexOf(x) <= list.indexOf(fromElement)
                    && list.indexOf(x) < list.indexOf(toElement)))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(MySortedSet<E> :: new));
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can’t use method references if you want to pass additional captured values as parameters. You will have to use a lambda expression instead:

```
MySortedSet<E> :: new
```

=>

```
() -> new MySortedSet<E>(c)
```